# MVC 5 - Get any username by userid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application that has a set of objects that reference back to the user that created them using the value obtained from:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

The problem is I need to be able to resolve the username for that account at any point so it can be displayed to the user when looking at a given object.

for clarity: I have a stored object, of which a property is UserId. I got that value from the above code at creation time. Somebody else is now logged in and needs to know the username associated with the userid that for that stored object.

Comment: could you not just query the db using linq?

Comment: Thanks jbutler. This is my fallback. I wouldn't want to do that directly from the controller for the sake or keeping concerns separated, it would require a new repository class etc. I just figured this kind of need would be pretty common and there would be a method call within the User/Identity framework.

Comment: That's not you're fall back, You're going to *have to* query the dataset in order to cross reference the id with name - that, or save the name instead (not safest option mind)

Comment: Cheers j, I appreciate that now. I had, clearly wrongly, assumed that the Identity framework would have had a quick access means of doing this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work without a lookup to the where your user information is stored.

You might consider implementing that lookups in a HTML helper to use it where ever you need it.

If you are using an OR-Mapper you should aim for joining the real users with your initial query.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I think this is going to have to be the way. I had kept the ASP identity tables and the rest of the site separated thus far but it seems a hard link or helper will be needed. You have my thanks. Ditto to others.

Answer (score 0):

use Session

```
 Session["Username"] = data.Username;
```

Comment: Would that not be for the current user though? I am talking from the perspective of having the userid as gained above, but nobody or somebody else could be logged on.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I came across it with the same question as the op.  In a comment he made to his own post the op said:

```
assumed ... Identity framework would have ... quick access ... of doing this
```

I believe the framework actually does have what the op was looking for, although I'm not certain it would be called quick.

When a UserManager is setup there is access to a method called

```
FindByName(username)
```

I used the answer in this [SO C# post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828744/get-username-by-userid-and-display-in-view) to clue me in to find this method.  That post was explaining how to go the other way, i.e. get the UserName from the UserID, but once the UserManager is setup, there are a number of Find... methods that can be used including the one noted above which is what the op was looking for.

The UserManager can be setup as follows in vb.net

```
Using appDb As New ApplicationDbContext
  Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(appDb)
  Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(userStore)
  Dim userID = myUserManager.FindByName(userName)
End Using
```

I don't know C# well enough to post that code; perhaps someone else can do that. Anyway, it worked for me.